# powershell - The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, object-model

When I try to add user/group using SharePoint OM or Power Shell script I'm getting the following error. In this example S-9-9044-V is an AD Group.

> The user does not exist or is not unique

```
$web = get-spweb "http://sharepoint/Year9.SCI"
$group = $web.sitegroups["Year9.SCI Students"]
$user = $web.EnsureUser("school\S-9-9044-V")
$group.AddUser($user)
```

I also noticed that this happens only for few AD groups and I'm able to add other users/groups successfully. Some suggested to reconfigure object cache user accounts but that doesn't help as I'm able to add other AD groups using the same script. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group was removed from Active Directory and that caused the issue, but people picker showed the group as available.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with User Profile, sometimes the profile is not created successfully or there is a profile sync problem! You can do it manually by running powershell:

[update UserProfile via Powershell with Set-SPUser](http://sharepointburger.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/specific-user-out-of-sync-with-ad-update-userprofile-via-powershell-with-set-spuser/)

If that doesn't help, try using the Group somewhere else like adding it in Windows Administrators or logging the system with this account! If that doesn't works that means the user/group is not created correctly in AD

Comment: I can add the AD group to Sharepoint using People picker but not through Powershell of OM