# Add user to Office 365 group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

How to add user to specific group in Office 365 ?

```
SPUser user1 = web.AllUsers["i:0#.f|membership|admin@test.onmicrosoft.com"];
//oeGroup.AddUser(user1);
web.SiteGroups["Team Site Members"].AddUser(user1);
//oeGroup.AddUser(user1.LoginName, user1.Email, user1.Name, user1.Notes);
//oeGroup.Users.Add(user1.LoginName, user1.Email, user1.Name, user1.Notes);
oeGroup.Update();
```

this is the code I used to add user but it give me a error

> The user does not exist or is not unique.

Comment: Check this thread http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57344/powershell-the-user-does-not-exist-or-is-not-unique

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
Add-SPOUser -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com -LoginName melissa.kerr@contoso.com -Group "Team Site Members"
```

Ref: [Add-SPOUser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161371%28v=office.15%29.aspx)